# Angular 7 direct url routing not working with id

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

If I click the navigation link I have code on button click it works fine

```
this.router.navigate(['/dashboard', this.selectedDateString]);
```

however, when I manually type in the url into the address bar like below

http://myapp/dashboard/01152020

I get a

### forbidden!

message. Why does routing work from within the app but not from direct address bar typing?

Here is my routing module

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'dashboard/:date', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },     
  { path: '',   redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes, { onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload' }
    )
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: Do you face this issue in dev mode ?

Comment: You should configure the server to return `index.html` if it receives requests at `/dashboard` (and any other frontend routes you may have).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with @TheHeadRush.

> Sounds like you don't have your server configured to handle the frontend routes by returning the base document from those endpoints.

If you don't want the server to handle that, you can tell Angular to use the [HashLocationStrategy](https://angular.io/api/common/HashLocationStrategy) which will use hash fragments to navigate to pages.

So instead of `http://myapp/dashboard/01152020`, your url will look like this in the browser `http://myapp#/dashboard/01152020`

You will provide it in your root app module like so.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MyFeatureModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy,
    },
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try testing it from `html` using `<a>` tag and router link like this

```
      <a [routerLink] = "['dashboard', selectedDateString]" href="javascript:;"></a>
```